# Selenide pressTab()

Tags: java, ide, selenide

I need to check is tabulation working when I click on the tag p [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39AAU.png) then press Tab key.

```
@org.junit.Test
    public void browserstackTabulation() {
        open("https://www.browserstack.com/guide/selenium-webdriver-tutorial");
        $(By.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'By Jash Unadkat, Technical Content')]")).pressTab();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't check that the element was highlighted after the tab button was pressed, but you can press the enter button and then check that the window is open.

```
$(By.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'By Jash Unadkat, Technical Content')]")).pressTab().pressEnter();
```